# iPhone: rotate the UIImageView inside a UIButton (Weird effect)

Tags: objective-c, iphone

My problem is that I want to rotate the `UIImageView` of a `UIButton`.
The transformation itself is pretty easy:

```
super.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((M_PI*120)/180);
```

(I subclass a button, but it doesn't work with a normal button either.)
So, it rotates but looks not very pretty: http://img534.imageshack.us/img534/2796/afterh.png

As reference, this is the same imageView but not rotated: 
http:// img704.imageshack.us/img704/1299/beforen.png (sorry for that whitespace, I'm new and can just post one link...)

Thanks for your help

Sebastian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, i finally got it.

It was needed to set the clipsToBounds property of the imageView to NO.

Sebstian